# JSP - forEach loop through arraylist

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In JSP

```
    <select name="roomMenu">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${visibleRooms}">
            <option>TEST</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

In Controller

```
ArrayList<Room> visibleRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
//code to fill visibleRooms with Room objects
model.addAttribute("visibleRooms", visibleRooms);
```

I know for a fact that visibleRooms array list has 4 items in it. But my drop down menu doesn't display any "TEST" options.

Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Can you put whole your controller action, not just 2 line of code? put this code in your jsp file: `${fn:length(visibleRooms)} to see length of list
`

Comment: It should work - see http://jsfiddle.net/kTfPR/. Try printing out the number of elements in the List with `${fn:length(visibleRooms)}` - if it says 0, then your list is not getting to your JSP or is empty...

Comment: @nickdos The problem is: `${visibleRooms}` is empty. This is not because of html is not showing options :(. Jsp engine is not generating them

Comment: You asked "is the syntax wrong" - I was simply showing that the expected HTML is valid... so you could rule that out. Next time be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. It says that fn:length is undefined though.

Comment: is `fn` inluced just like you did for jstl `c`? `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"                                                  prefix="fn" %>` Post your controller action code, none is gona steal it :)

Comment: You guys are right, the visibleRooms is listed as having 0 items in the JSP.

Comment: Could you please post the complete controller method.